# Tracking number of IOs to disk on Windows

Tags: backup, windows-7, performance-monitoring, performance

I'm trying to compare 2 versions of a backup software product.
I setup all IO to go to a dedicated drive.

Is there a way with performance monitor (or anything else) to track the number of IO operations.

I know I can measure disk queue length and different stats like that, but I'd like to know the exact number of IO operations.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows 7, but if needed I could go to Windows 2008 or 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metric you are looking for is "Disk Transfers/sec" under "Physical Disk" in Performance Monitor.
[image: Screen-capture of PerfMon setting]